# create php file to check database frequently

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

How I can create a php file to check mysql database if there is new row inserted ?

any article for this ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: use a cron job ? What do you want it to do if there has been ?

Comment: if there is a new row inserted i need to display it in android application i already developed

Comment: modify the insert script to send a push notification to the app

Comment: nice but how i can do this ?! give me an article or example please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use google cloud messaging and modify your insert script

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

the google site has API examples